# Combining <symbol> with <use> SVG tags on a HTML page

Tags: html, svg, symbols

I'm trying to combine the 'symbol' and 'use' SVG elements in an HTML page and I can't seem to get it to play ball.

I've declared the original graphic within a div at the top of the page using 'symbol', and then called this afterwards with 'use'.  The original graphic then duly shows.

When I try and repeat it further down it doesn't show.  When I inspect the page though, there is some space being allocated for this element despite it not showing / rendering and the svg 'shadow root' is showing.

Any help would be awesome.

```css
#box1, #box2 {width: 300px;}
```

```html
<div id="box1">
  <symbol id="shapes-square" viewBox="0 0 352.16 240.77">
    <svg id="square" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 195.74 129.42">
      <title>Blue Square</title>
      <rect x="0.5" y="0.5" width="194.74" height="128.42" fill="blue" stroke="#000" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
    </svg>
  </symbol>
</div>

<!-- Declare Initial 'use' of SVG -->
<svg>
    <use href="#shapes-square" />
</svg>

<br />

<!-- Div to hold the second 'use' of the SVG -->
<div id="box2">
   <svg>
    <use href="#shapes-square" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: @Chenmunka Please don't suggest edits to remove tags. This takes at least three people to review, whereas people with >2k rep can do these edits singlehandedly. We appreciate your willingness to cooperate, but this is unfortunately not the right way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `<symbol>` tag has to be wrapped inside the `<svg>` in order for you to use it subsequently. Please check out this article that could help you further https://css-tricks.com/svg-symbol-good-choice-icons/

```css
#box1, #box2 {width: 300px;}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display:none">  
  <symbol id="shapes-square" viewBox="0 0 195.74 129.42"> 
      <rect x="0.5" y="0.5" width="194.74" height="128.42" fill="blue" stroke="#000" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
  </symbol>
</svg>

<!-- Declare Initial 'use' of SVG -->
<div id="box1">
  <svg>
      <title>Blue Square 1</title>
      <use href="#shapes-square"/>
  </svg>
</div>

<br />

<!-- Div to hold the second 'use' of the SVG -->
<div id="box2">
   <svg>
      <title>Blue Square 2</title>
    <use href="#shapes-square" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Swap the tags `<symbol>` and `<svg>`

`<symbol>` serves for temporary concealment of content, it is used recently, most often in sprites, since it has its own internal `viewBox`, for additional positioning of elements.

```css
#box1, #box2 {width: 300px;}
```

```html
<div id="box1">
  
    <svg id="square" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 195.74 129.42">
<symbol id="shapes-square" viewBox="0 0 352.16 240.77">     
  <title>Blue Square</title>
      <rect x="0.5" y="0.5" width="194.74" height="128.42" fill="blue" stroke="#000" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
   </symbol>  
  </svg>
  
</div>

<!-- Declare Initial 'use' of SVG -->
<svg>
    <use href="#shapes-square" />
</svg>

<br />

<!-- Div to hold the second 'use' of the SVG -->
<div id="box2">
   <svg>
    <use href="#shapes-square" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

*In the future, you probably want to use styling for cloned objects. In this case, there may be some nuances:*

- When you reuse the content with `<use>` it enters the shadow DOM

  And it becomes impossible to change the styles of cloned objects from external tables `CSS`
  To eliminate this defect, you can force inheritance of properties for svg elements.

  `rect{
       fill:inherit;
       stroke:inherit;
       stroke-width:inherit;
       }`
- In addition, you can use the coordinates of `x` and`y` inside
  `<use>` for additional positioning of cloned objects.

  `<use class="use1" x="0" y="10" href="#shapes-square" />`

**Below is an example of styling cloned objects**

```css
  rect{
 fill:inherit;
 stroke:inherit;
 stroke-width:inherit;
 }
.use1{ fill:red;} 
.use2{ fill:yellowgreen;} 
.use3{ fill:dodgerblue;} 

 #box1, #box2, #box3 {
 background:#D5D5D5;
 width: 400px; 
 margin:4px;
 }
```

```html
<div>
  
    <svg id="square" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="195" height="129 "viewBox="0 0 195.74 129.42">
<symbol id="shapes-square" viewBox="0 0 195.74 129.42">     
  <title>Blue Square</title>
      <rect x="0.5" y="0.5" width="194.74" height="128.42" fill="blue" stroke="#000" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
   </symbol>  
  </svg>
  
</div>

<div id="box1">
<svg>
    <use class="use1" x="0" y="10" href="#shapes-square" />
</svg>
</div>


<!-- Div to hold the second 'use' of the SVG -->
<div id="box2">
   <svg>
    <use class="use2" x="50" y="10"  href="#shapes-square" />
  </svg>
</div>  

<div id="box3">
   <svg>
    <use class="use3" x="20" y="10"  href="#shapes-square" />
  </svg>
</div>
```